# Adding rows of missing data in SAS

Tags: sas

Consider the following schema of a data set named test:

```
 id   time  pulse
 1    0      120
 1    5      100
 1    10     80
 1    15     50
 2    0      110
 2    5      70
 2    10     60
 3    0      114
 .    .      .
 .    .      .
```

Notice that time 15 is missing for id 2. I want to add a row for id 2 showing time 15 and a missing value (NA) in the pulse column. I want to do this for all ids with any missing values. How would I do this in SAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how large your dataset is, you can use the COMPLETETYPES option in PROC SUMMARY to do this for you.  This runs in memory and can cause problems with very large datasets.

```
data have;
input id   time  pulse;
datalines;
 1    0      120
 1    5      100
 1    10     80
 1    15     50
 2    0      110
 2    5      70
 2    10     60
 3    0      114
 .    .      .
 .    .      .
 ;
 run;

 proc summary data=have nway completetypes;
 class id time;
 id pulse;
 output out=want (drop=_:);
 run;
```

Comment: Hi Keith, wanted to read a bit more about this so I looked at the proc means documentation, and came across this: "Using COMPLETETYPES does not increase the memory requirements."

Do you have any more info on how completetypes impacts memory?

Source: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146729.htm

Comment: It's not so much the COMPLETETYPES option, but PROC SUMMARY in general, particularly when using the ID statement.  In this instance there is only one variable, but I've found if you put in multiple variables it can cause memory failures.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `lag` function to pull through the previous time. If you know the times occur in a set order (0,5,10,15) then by comparing the time in the current row to the lagged value you know if you need to insert a new row. This can be done with the `output` function

Answer (score 0):

I would say `proc transpose` works perfectly fine for your situation. It will fill in the missing values for you while changing the data from long format to wide format.

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=HAVE OUT=WANT (drop=_name_);
    VAR PULSE;
    BY ID;
    ID TIME; 
RUN;
```

Then you just need to change the data `WANT` back to long format.